# Why are the loops for memset() 1M times and 10M times cost the same time?

Tags: c++, loops, memset

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* a = (char*)malloc(1024);
    int times = 10000000;
    struct timeval begin, end;
    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++){
        memset(a, 1, 1024);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    cout << end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec << "." << end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I set times to 1M, the output is about 0.13 second, however when I set times to 10M, the output is still about 0.13 second. What causes such circumstance? Is it caused by the optimisation of Linux or the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: optimisation disabled

I think you need to use more precise `chrono` instead of `time.h` and disable compiler optimisations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <chrono>

#ifdef __GNUC__
    #ifdef __clang__
        static void test() __attribute__ ((optnone)) {
    #else
        static void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) test() {
    #endif
#elif _MSC_VER
    #pragma optimize( "", off )
        static void test() {
#else
    #warning Unknow compiler!
        static void test() {
#endif

    char* a = (char*) malloc(1024);

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        memset(a, 1, 1024);
    }
    std::cout<<"Finished in "<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()<<std::endl;
}

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma optimize("", on)
#endif

int main() {
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

10M: Finished in 259.851
1M: Finished in 26.3928

Comment: One more note. You can set a random generated value in memset() call to avoid compiler optimisations, if any.

Comment: `#warning Unknown compiler!` doesn't make sense, since `#warning` is a non-standard, compiler-specific feature to begin with. Or was this added in some later C++ standard that I'm not up to date with?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, `#warning` is a non-standard, it can be replaced by `#error`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used a g++ compiler under Linux environment, when I compiled, I used the -O0 option( g++ -O0 a.cpp ), but this didn't work. On the other hand, if this is caused by optimisation, when happened when compiler compile this program?

Comment: @GwanHe Your `memset()` call may be dropped by an optimizing compiler. Read this [article](http://www.eliteraspberries.com/blog/2012/10/zero-and-forget--caveats-of-zeroing-memory-in-c.html) or [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC06-C.+Beware+of+compiler+optimizations) for example. By the way, above listed code works as expected with gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.7.

Comment: Understood. Thanks :)